# WS-Security with Apache Camel and Spring-WS

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-ws

I'm currently writing a webservice server in Camel, and need to implement WS-Security (encrypt/sign).
In other projects i've used Spring-WS, so i figured i'd use Camel's implementation as well.

I figured i'd just configure a Wss4jSecurityInterceptor, but when i try implement it, i find that the entire org.springframework.ws.soap.security.* namespace is missing from the spring-ws package.

Is WS-Security only supported with Apache CXF ?

Edit: Here's how i've setup the route:

```
from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://schemas.somewhere.dk/}operation?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
.process(MyProcessor)
.to("jms:queue:test.out");
```

Comment: Could you please provide some information about the route and it's configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found that running "mvn eclipse:eclipse" had messed up my Eclipse project files, which in turn was causing Eclipse to not update dependencies.
After a quick delete/import existing maven projects, things look as expected.